# Tuning Gabor filter

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filtering, wavelet

I am trying to seek out pathologies in pictures of noisy vertical stacked layers
with Gabor filtering. For each column, i regard the neigborhood with 10 pixels to the left and right and filter the part of the image with the gabor kernel. Then I take the frobenious norm, so that I have for each column a scalar value.

---

Here is my result using that image posted below. For me it seems *counterintuitive* that the response of 0 degree is that much higher than the response of 45 degrees.

[image: Gabor Results]

But the desired effect is satisfied, meaning that i can state a condition such that the pathology near the 300th column is hit using that the value of 0 degrees is below the value of 45 degrees.
I expected the other way round or is my image just too noisy?

So my **questions** are: How can I refine the parameter *lambda* and *gamma* to maximize the effect when the structure of vertcal stacked layers are broken?(in the middle of the picture around column 290 - 320)

When I tried to change parameters I got too much false positives such that i can not distinguish anymore.

And how can it be that the values of 0 degree is that greater than the filter response of 45 degrees? For me it seems very odd considering that image.

### ================

Here is the image

[image: Image with small pathology in the mid]

---

Here is my code

```
windowRadius = 10;
bw = 1;
for k=0:23
   theta(k+1)= k*pi/12;
end
psi     = [0 pi/2];
lambda  = 8; % std value 8
gamma   = 0.5; % std value 0.5
for colIndx=1: size(Img,2)
   if colIndx-windowRadius < 1
       left = 1;
   else
       left = colIndx - windowRadius;
   end

   if colIndx+windowRadius > size(Img,2)
       right = size(Img,2);
   else
       right = colIndx + windowRadius;
   end

   for i=1:length(theta)
       gb{i} = gabor_fn(bw,gamma,psi(1),lambda,theta(i)) ...
          + 1i * gabor_fn(bw,gamma,psi(2),lambda,theta(i));
   end

   gabor_out0deg{colIndx} = imfilter(Img(:, left : right),gb{1},'symmetric');
   gabor_out45deg{colIndx} = imfilter(Img(:, left : right),gb{4},'symmetric');
   gabor_out90deg{colIndx} = imfilter(Img(:, left : right),gb{7},'symmetric');

   gaborFroNorm0deg(colIndx) = norm(gabor_out0deg{colIndx},'fro') / ((right - left) * size(Img,1));
   gaborFroNorm45deg(colIndx)= norm(gabor_out45deg{colIndx},'fro') / ((right - left) * size(Img,1));
   gaborFroNorm90deg(colIndx)= norm(gabor_out90deg{colIndx},'fro') / ((right - left) * size(Img,1));

end
```

Comment: Try using `imgaborfilt`: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaborfilt.html

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but still I dont know if a high wavelength is suitable for me or not and why the maginitude of 0 degree is much greater than the magnitute of 45 degrees.

Comment: Using the sobel filter gets me expected results that the magnitude of 0 degrees is the weakest one, but unfortunalety i dont need the sobel filter.